# Parsing a 2-Dimensional Matrix from a file in C

Tags: c

I'm a newbe in C programming and searching for a programming approach to solve a problem. As my first software to program I try to read in a 2-dimensional matrix from a text-file and store it in an Array. My intention is to compare the numbers in the string for an old-school shortest path algorithm in a graph.

First I had an approach of reading in each row, parsing it with fscanf and store each row in a 2-dimensional array with strcpy. Although I managed to use fprint in a loop to put it on the display, there seems to be a structural infeasability to copy several []-rows in one [][]-matrix. The compiler totures me with nasty comments like "transfering of argument 2 with incompatible pointer type" regarding the strcpy. The hole idea seems to be a infeasable dead-end in C.

So has anybody an idea of how to read in a matrix from file and have it in a unified string-array for comparison of the values? Pointers, structures, anything? A nice solution would be a possiblity to read in the matrix as several float varibles.

Maybe some of you guys with more experience has an idea?

Thanks!
Threx

Comment: 2 upvotes. Seriously? Is SO that broken?

Comment: You need to post your coding attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way your text file is structured. If all the numbers in the file are like this

```
11223344
44556677
```

then you could use something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    

char *charbuffer, ROWS, COLS;
char matrix[ROWS][COLS]
for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        if (fgets(charbuffer, 3, file)) {
            matrix[row][col] = strdup(charbuffer);
        }
    }
}
```

where `fgets(buffer, n, file)` gets `n - 1` characters from `file` a time and saves `n` characters to `buffer` (that extra character is the string terminating `\0`). In this particular case, the first iteration would get `11`, save `11\0` to the buffer and copy it to the buffer.

Make sure you understand the [differences between `strcpy` and `strdup`](http://careerride.com/c-strdup%28%29-and-strcpy%28%29.aspx). The loop above would fail and fill your matrix with `77`s.

If your file has a different structure, you could replace the `fgets` with an appropriate function like `fscanf`.

**Edit**: `strdup` is a POSIX function. In case you happen to be using Windows or don't have the function available, you could use this:

```
char *strdup(const char *string) {
    char *pointer = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    if (pointer) { 
        strcpy(pointer, string); 
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your matrix to a string pass it as string, and in the function that you send the string to as a parameter, SPLIT the split back into an array.

## EDIT

Oops please ignore my idea as i didnt read the full question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using for the matrix only a one dimensional array?

With a little bit of math you could read every entry for example:
`matrix[i * columns + j]`
gives you the element on `i` row and `j` column.